# return distinct filename with comma separated pages?

Tags: sql, ms-access

In the pictured example, I'd like to some how return test1.pdf, 1,2 and test2,pdf, 45,39
Is there a way to do this?

**Table example**

[image: Table example]

Comment: There's SELECT DISTINCT filename, COUNT(page) from test GROUP by filename, but I don't really care for count function; is there some other function I'm unaware of, that can comma separate the pages as one value?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't know any way in SQL you could do this. I'm afraid you'll need and VBA built-in fuction to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a fake database with a single table named `Tabla1`.

That table got 3 fields: ID, Filename and Page

[image]

Then I made a query with this SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tabla1.filename, GET_PAGES([filename]) AS Pages
FROM Tabla1;
```

And it returns this:

[image]

Notice in the SQL code I call for a VBA UDF created in a module. The code of the function GET_PAGES is this one:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function GET_PAGES(vThisFilename As String) As String
Dim MiSQL As String
Dim STR As String
STR = ""
MiSQL = "SELECT Tabla1.page FROM Tabla1 WHERE (((Tabla1.FileName) = '" & vThisFilename & "')) ORDER BY Tabla1.Id;"

Dim RST As Recordset

Set RST = Application.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(MiSQL, 2, 4)

If RST.RecordCount > 0 Then
    RST.MoveLast
    RST.MoveFirst
End If

Do Until RST.EOF = True
    STR = STR & RST.Fields(0).Value & ","
    RST.MoveNext
Loop

RST.Close
Set RST = Nothing
DoEvents

'we get rid of last comma

GET_PAGES = Left(STR, Len(STR) - 1)

End Function
```

To add the function to your database, just add a module and copy/paste the code into that module. If you read the code, you will notice we do an SQL petition of pages, filtered by filenames, and **sorted by ID field**.

`MiSQL = "SELECT Tabla1.page FROM Tabla1 WHERE (((Tabla1.FileName) = '" & vThisFilename & "')) ORDER BY Tabla1.Id;"`

This is really important, because ordering by ID allows me to show the pages numbers in the exact order they've been entered in `Tabla1`. Not sorting could result in showing the pages ordered by their values (1,2 for test1.pdf and 39,45 for test2.pdf).

If you are planning to use this in long recordsets, it may overcharge and slow down the calculations.

Hope this helps.